What is on these Dryas leaves?
I saw these Dryas (octopetala or integrifolia, I'm not sure) in Svalbard. They have some white substance on them. At first I thought it was a fungal infection, but then looking at them under the microscope it looks like salt excretion. Is that something Dryas can do? What's going on here?




Is the Dryas healthy? It could still be fungal, just internal and starting to break out of the leaf. Could be salt secretions (don't know if Dryas does this), could be wax. Since you have a microscope, could you put some on a slide and take some photos?

Crystals look like crystals (especially under magnification), fungus looks more like fuzz/hair. A wet prep is easy; make a saline solution (1 tsp. table salt in 2 cups water), scrape the fuzzy stuff and stir it into solution. Put a drop on a clean slide and cover with a cover slip or another clean slide. Hyphae have a very distinct appearance. Let us know what you find!

Unfortunately these pictures are all I have. I took them when I was still on-site, and Svalbard prohibits taking plant samples off the island, so I couldn't bring any home with me. I tended to see the white substance on all the leaves of an individual plant, rather than on individual leaves on different plants. I haven't found any mention of salt excretions in Dryas literature, but I may be looking in the wrong places.
